# How to be notified of another app's crash?

Tags: android

Is it somehow possible to create a "monitoring" app (assuming we have the appropriate permission level) which is notified when a specific app stops running ?

In other words, is there such an API that would allow to register on a third party app's lifecycle ?

Comment: Seems u can read system log to indicate an app's crash and stack trace. I saw apps doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) can be used to get stats on apps running on a device but requires a settings permission.

A work around could be to get all foreground apps running on a device periodically ... say every 20 mins using a library like [jaredrummler-android-processes](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses) (which doesn't require any permissions but works on Android KitKat to Marshmallow). Then try to compare the set of apps between each period. 
The set difference would reveal which foreground apps have stopped running.

Perhaps using a combination of the above two approaches would be best.